# Custom pages missing on "front page" setting

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, frontpage

I have a custom post type with 9 custom pages on WP 4.5.

When I got to Settings -> Reading -> A static page -> front page dropdown,

I see a list of all the standard wp pages plus at most 5 of my custom pages (the most recent 5 of them).

I have no clue on why just 5 and I need to show all of them.

I'm using this code to load them on the dropdown:

```
function my_custom_add_to_dropdown( $pages, $r ){
if('page_on_front' == $r['name']){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mytype'
    );
    $stacks = get_posts($args);
    $pages = array_merge($pages, $stacks);
}
return $pages;
}
add_filter( 'get_pages', 'my_custom_add_to_dropdown', 10, 2 );
```

I have checked with print_r($stack) and the output is of the most recent 5 custom post pages. I need all 9 of them there. (I always want all of them there)

Anyone can help me? What I must change to unlock all the custom post pages to show up?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show all custom post pages then you need to add:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mytype',
    'showposts' => '-1',
);
```

Hope above code is help

Comment: there should be `numberposts` instead of `showposts`